# performace slows down when using QString::split function

Tags: c++, string, performance, optimization, qt5

there's a text file which can possibly contain up to `5*10^6` 2D points.

After a bit of experimenting measuring and playing with the code that reads this file I found out that the bottleneck is where I'm splitting read line into a parts using `QString::split` function like this:

```
QString x, y; QStringList lineParts;   
while (!inputSream.atEnd())
{
    line = inputSream.readLine();
    if (line.size() > 0)
    {
        if (! line.contains("#"))
        {
        >>  lineParts = line.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);  //  performance go down by a almost ~2 seconds

            x = lineParts.at(0);
            y = lineParts.at(1);

            QPointF p;
            qreal yd = y.toDouble();
            p.setX(x.toDouble());
            p.setY(yd);

            if (yd < yRanges.first)
                yRanges.first = yd;      //  minY

            if (yd > yRanges.second)
                yRanges.second = yd;     //  maxY

            points.push_back(p);

        } else
        {
            headers.push_back(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Without this function it reads the file almost 2 times faster

Why is `QString` splitting operates so slow ?

What can be done to improve performance of this operation without writing own split function ?

**p.s.**

I was thinking to separate the whole file reading with 2 threads, where one of them reads line into a buffer and emits file read done signal for a  correspondent slot that would do some other stuff with the points.

But this sounds to me like a little overhead and no performance gain because it wouldn't differ much as it still would be doing synchronous operation which is: "while the line is not read it coudn't be parsed" thus I think its better to do faster splitting of the string

Comment: => you shall profile. There's no other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Qt5.4 and above,

use "`QString::splitRef`". this will be faster.

The `split` returns, copies of sub strings in to a list of `Qstring`.This has an additional burden of memory allocation.

The `splitRef` returns, substring references (copy of data only) in to a vector of `QStringRef`. This avoids the burden of memory allocation as only references are returned.

The documentation says: "**This class(QStringRef) is designed to improve the performance of substring handling when manipulating substrings obtained from existing QString instances. QStringRef avoids the memory allocation and reference counting overhead of a standard QString by simply referencing a part of the original string.** "

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringref.html#details

***Note:*** you should be careful of original strings life or scope."**All references are valid as long this string is alive. Destroying this string will cause all references be dangling pointers**."
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#splitRef

Comment: yeah, thanks for suggesting this function, it gave a little speed up of 0.4 sec, just was expecting more performance gain with it